How to Interrupt Text-to-Speech Playback When User Speaks
I am working on a voice assistant project in Python. The assistant listens to the user's input, generates a response using a language model, and then speaks the response using AWS Polly. I want the assistant to stop speaking its response immediately if the user starts speaking again while the assistant is still talking.
THIS IS THE CODE:
def text_to_speech(text):
    try:
        # Initialize AWS session with credentials
        boto_session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            region_name='AWS_REGION'  # Adjust region as needed
        )

        # Create a new Polly client
        polly_client = boto_session.client('polly')

        # Synthesize speech
        response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(
            Text=text,
            OutputFormat='mp3',
            VoiceId='Raveena'  # Adjust voice as needed
        )

        # Save synthesized audio to a temporary file
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.mp3', delete=False) as f:
            audio_file_path = f.name
            f.write(response['AudioStream'].read())

        # Initialize pygame mixer
        pygame.mixer.init()

        # Load and play audio file
        pygame.mixer.music.load(audio_file_path)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

        # Start listening for interruptions
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
            while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
                print("Listening for interruption...")
                audio = recognizer.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=0.5)
                try:
                    text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                    if text:
                        print("Interruption detected!")
                        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                        break
                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    pass
                except sr.RequestError as e:
                    print(f"Could not request results; {e}")

        # Clean up temporary file
        os.remove(audio_file_path)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Error during text to speech:", ex)

